# Как в Notepad++ найти файлы без определенного слова?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Как выглядит регулярное выражение для Notepad++, при котором бы, я смог искать файлы, в которых нет слова "var", например?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете имитировать это поведение, используя негативный просмотр вперед:

`^((?!var).)*$`

Регулярное выражение выше будет соответствовать любой строке, или линии без разрыва строки, не содержащей (суб) строку «var». Это не то, что регулярное выражение «хорошо» в (или должны делать), но все же, это возможно.